# Perl - Rename image files in directory

Tags: perl

I don't use perl a whole bunch. I have a list of image files that I need to be renamed with an incrementing counter.

```
images folder

image_1_0.jpg
image_1_1.jpg
image_2_0.jpg
image_2_1.jpg
image_3_0.jpg
image_3_1.jpg
image_3_2.jpg
image_4_0.jpg
image_5_0.jpg
image_5_1.jpg
image_5_2.jpg
image_5_3.jpg
image_5_4.jpg
image_5_5.jpg
```

```
output would be

1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
4.jpg
5.jpg
6.jpg
7.jpg
8.jpg
9.jpg
10.jpg
11.jpg
12.jpg
13.jpg
14.jpg
15.jpg
```

What I currently have

```
my $dir = usr/local/bin/images

my counter = 0;

opendir (IMGDIR, "$dir") or die "Cannot open directory: $!";
my @files = readdir(IMGDIR);

foreach my $oldfile(@files){
    (my $oldfileb = $oldfile =~ s/\.[^.]+$//; #get file without extention
    my $newfile = $dir/"$counter".jpg;

    rename ("$dir/$oldfileb", "dir/$newfile");counter++;
}
```

Trying to use it more Perl more, but could use some help with this. Error is giving at the counter portion of code

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the [rename](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/File-Rename/rename.PL) utility.

Comment: Apparently you are getting errors. You should include those when asking for help. Also you should use `use strict; use warnings;` to get critical information about your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start the script with

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
```

See [strict](http://p3rl.org/strict) and [warnings](http://p3rl.org/warnings). Perl will protect you from the most common errors.

Strings must be enclosed in quotes and every statement should end with a semicolon if another statement follows it:

```perl
my $dir = 'usr/local/bin/images';
```

Variables must start with a sigil:

```perl
my $counter = 0;
```

Parentheses must be closed:

```perl
(my $oldfileb = $oldfile) =~ s/\.[^.]+$//;
```

Since Perl 5.14, you can also use the more readable `/r` modifier:

```perl
my $oldfileb = $oldfile =~ s/\.[^.]+$//r;
```

Note that you should skip files that don't look like image names ([readdir](http://p3rl.org/readdir) will return `.` and `..` on *nix, for example). You also might want to [sort](http://p3rl.org/sort) the files.

`/` outside of quotes is division, `.` is concatenation.

```perl
my $newfile = "$dir/$counter.jpg";
```

You already included `$dir` in `$newfile`:

```perl
rename "$dir/$oldfileb", $newfile;
```

Check the return value of [rename](http://p3rl.org/rename) for errors.

```perl
rename "$dir/$oldfileb", $newfile or warn "Can't rename $oldfile: $!";
```

Comment: Updated the script and corrected my mistakes thanks guys. The script ran with no errors but is not rename the file so they all stayed the same. @choroba

Comment: @Trey: Try printing the filenames as you progress. Maybe the script doesn't find any file?

Comment: You surely want to add a `natsort` (from [Sort::Key::Natural](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Key::Natural)) in there